# Function gets called before label, but the label should have been printed first

Tags: python, tkinter

Somehow, my Tkinter code is calling the function before displaying the label, however, the label should have come first.

```
def doAction():
    global e
    text = tk.Label(root, text="Processing.")
    text.grid(row=2, columns=1)
    main()

import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("App")

e = tk.Entry(root)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
e.focus_set()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Go", command=doAction)
button.grid(row=0, column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

The idea behind is to display first "Processing" and then let the function "main()" do its thing.

Comment: How long does `main()` run for? What is inside `main()`? Can you put it in another thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once it enters `main()`, something there is blocking the main thread, hence `mainloop()` cannot update. You will have to force update it before it calls `main()`.

```
def doAction():
    .....
    text.grid(row=2, columns=1)

    root.update() # Now the event loop will start processing before the function ends
    main()
```

It is not a good idea to freeze the GUI with whatever you are doing inside `main()`, if it does not have code related to `tkinter` you could start a new thread for `main()`.

Comment: This worked perfectly well. I would copy paste the main() function but it's 250 lines of code. The function main() scrapes Twitter and cleans up the scrapped data.

Comment: @user14903989 Hmmmm better to put it inside a new thread